# Including dependencies from a test artifact in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm writing a module `utils` that will be used for in my application `myapp`. Some of the classes that are in `utils` only used for tests

the sbt contains those definitions:

`build.sbt` in `utils`:

```
name := "utils"

organization := "com.mycompany"

publishArtifact in Test := true

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.exteranl1" %% "external1" % "1.0.0"
  )
```

`build.sbt` in `myapp`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.mycompany" %% "utils" % "1.0.0",
    "com.mycompany" %% "utils" % "1.0.0" % "test" classifier "tests"
)
```

And this works for me.
I can use `external1` in `myapp`, and in tests of `myapp` I can use classes defined in the tests of `utils`

My problem is when I try to add `external2` that will be used only in tests, and therefore I don't want it included in the `compile` artifact (of both `utils` and `myapp`)

I tried to modify the `utils` `build.sbt` like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.exteranl1" %% "external1" % "1.0.0",
    "com.exteranl2" %% "external2" % "1.0.0" % "test"
  )
```

but `external2` is not present in the compiled tests of `myapp`.

My workaround is to add `external2` to `myapp` as well:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.mycompany" %% "utils" % "1.0.0",
    "com.mycompany" %% "utils" % "1.0.0" % "test" classifier "tests",
    "com.exteranl2" %% "external2" % "1.0.0" % "test"
)
```

but that is not very convenient since I need to track in `myapp` all the packages used in `utils` tests.

So my question is,
can I mark somehow `external2` in `utils` to tell the compiler to add it as a dependency in `myapp`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `external2` only exists in utils in the test context, it is not picked up by anything that uses `utils` because it only sees `utils` not `utils`'s tests as a dependency. If you are using *sbt* [multi-project configuration](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project), you can explicitly declare this test dependency in `myapp` with:

```
dependencies := Seq(utils % "compile->compile;test->test")
```

If these are separate projects and you are pulling `utils` in from a local ivy repository, i believe you have to declare `external2` explicitly.